# Fetching the column id in a table using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have this table structure.

```
<table id = "table1">
   <thead>
      <tr id = "header_row">
         <th> <a id = "a1">ABC</a> </th>
         <th> <a id = "a2">DEF</a> </th>
         <th> <a id = "a3">GHI</a> </th>
         <th> <a id = "a4">JKL</a> </th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tr>.....data filling up the table.....</tr>
   <tr>.............</tr>
   .
   .
</table>
```

So from this table, I want to fetch the value "a2", Can you please tell me how to do this? Thanks!

EDIT: There are many other `<a>` `<table>` tags on the page, so if there is any way to extract using the id?

Comment: `$('a').on('click', function(e){e.preventDefault();alert(this.id); })`

Comment: @RayonDabre But that would conflict with other `<a>` tags in the page, and can you do it without `onclick`?

Comment: That was just a hint... `$('table#table1 a').on('click', function(e){e.preventDefault();alert(this.id); })` will be more specific!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So from this table, I want to fetch the value "a2"

You mean fetch the id of second column in the header row?

Try this

```
$("#header_row th a:eq(1)").attr("id")
```

If you simply wants to fetch **ABC** of a know `a` based on its `id` then

```
$("#a2").html(); //or text()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get by this `$("#a2").text();`

Answer (score 1):

To fetch the value of the `#a2` you can simply do:

Plain JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('a2').innerHtml;
```

jQuery:

```
$('#a2').text();
```

---

A side note. This sentence:

> So from this table, I want to fetch the value "a2"

makes me think that you're using the same `id`s for different tables in the same page and you want to retrieve data from a specific one, aren't you? 
This situation is wrong, `id`s **MUST** be unique in your whole page so if this is your case consider using classes